# SELECT records using multiple critira

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table named all_data with fields date, value, and other fields.

I need to select last 7, 14, and 30 days from the database. There can be several entries with the same date like

```
date      value
10-25-16   30
10-25-16   24
10-26-16   42
```

Here is the SELECT Statment I have that works for less than 30 days

```
$sql = "SELECT type_entry, COUNT(value) as val_count, FLOOR(SUM(value)) as sum_glu FROM all_data
    WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 30 AND type_entry = 'Glucose'
     ORDER BY date";
```

I want the same query 2 more times but changing the DATEDIFF statement with <14 and <7 so I end up with val_count1, val_count2, val_count3, sum_glu1, sum_glu2, sumglu3 I will use those to calculate the average of each.

I do not know enough SQL to figure out how to do it.

Here is a sample of readings

```
10/17/2016 116
10/17/2016 277
10/17/2016 145
10/18/2016 150
10/18/2016 125
10/19/2016 200
```

I need the number of records from 10/19/2016 for 7 days then I can do a weekly average of the readings.

[image]

Comment: So all you want is how many records appeared for 7 days after `10/19/2016` ?

Comment: Yes, but it would be before and including the last record.
Example - There are 18 records from 10/20/2016 and 10/27/2016 then I want to sum all the values in those records then divide by the number of records to get the average.

Comment: Huh?  Do you want 7 days or until the last record?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Want to thank you for taking the time to answer this question and teaching me more about Stackflow.

Comment: Is there any other information I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT type_entry,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS val_count_30,
       FLOOR(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 30 THEN value ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_glu_30,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS val_count_14,
       FLOOR(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 14 THEN value ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_glu_14,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS val_count_7,
       FLOOR(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 7 THEN value ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_glu_7
FROM all_data
WHERE type_entry = 'Glucose'
ORDER BY date
```

If you just want the average of `value` for a 7 day period starting on `10/19/2016` for 7 days then you can just use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT type_entry,
       AVG(value) AS avgValue
FROM all_data
WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-10-19' AND DATE_ADD('2016-10-19', INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND 
      type_entry = 'Glucose'
GROUP BY type_entry
```

Comment: Update your question accordingly and explain what you mean by the last date.

Comment: Do _not_ post that here.

Comment: Sorry new to stackflow. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: I need to use the last date in the database as the starting date, not the NOW date. How would I get the date of the last record so I can calulate a true average.

Comment: If you use the last date in the database as the starting date then how can you have one week's worth of records?

Comment: These date and values are users blood sugar results. They take their blood reading several times a day. They need to know what the average readings are for the last 7, 14, and 30  days of readings.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can retrieve all rows with criteria `< 30` and all your following criterias contain within this one. You could add a `CASE` expression within aggregate functions to only perform aggregation within rows that match your criteria. All I did was changed the `< X` for every pair of columns:

```
SELECT 
  type_entry, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 30 THEN value END) as val_count1, 
  FLOOR(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 30 THEN value END)) as sum_glu1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 14 THEN value END) as val_count2, 
  FLOOR(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 14 THEN value END)) as sum_glu2,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 7 THEN value END) as val_count3, 
  FLOOR(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 7 THEN value END)) as sum_glu3 
FROM all_data
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) < 30 AND type_entry = 'Glucose'
GROUP BY type_entry
ORDER BY date
```

Also, note that I added the missing `GROUP BY` clause. Even though MySQL allows it, many different databases would yield an error. The recommended way is not to rely on MySQL mechanism in this matter.